# run function to element of inner list of a nest list and append the output while maintaining the nested list structure

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a list of dictionary which I will be using the the key and values to pass as parameter of a function. The function does some calculation to these key and values. What I want to achieve is this:

```
dList = [{k1:v1, k2:v2, k3:v3}, {k4:v4, k5:v5}, {k6:v6 k7:v7,k8:v8}]

finalList = [[kv1, kv2, kv3], [kv4,kv5], [kv6,kv7,kv8]] 
#kv(number) is the return values of the function
```

but what I am getting is this:

```
finalList = [kv1,kv2,kv3,kv4,kv5,kv6,kv7,kv8]
```

How do I maintain the nested list structure ?

Here is my code :

```
setUpTime = []
dList = []
fList = []
for x in range(len(dList)):
    for d in dList:
        if d == dList[x]:
            for k , v in d.items():
                temp = setupTime(k, v)
                setUpTime.append(temp)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `finalList = [[setupTime(k, v) for (k,v) in d.items()] for d in dList]`?

Comment: let me try this

Comment: You need to create a new nested list each time through the outer loop.

Comment: @ArifRashed Isn't that what `setupTime(k, v)` does?

Comment: Why do you need the `for x in range(len(dList)):` loop? `for d in dList:` already loops over all the elements in the list.

Comment: @quamrana thank you so much ! this worked! I am pretty bad at list comprehension thus I do it the long way.

Comment: @Barmar I thought I could use the length as an Index, so I could use the index of the list to maintain the nested structure. However, it did not work out as I thought it would.

Comment: But you're not using the index in the nested structure anywhere. And if you want an index, use `for i, d in enumerate(dList):`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an inner list each time through the outer loop. You append the results of the function to that list, and then append that list to the final result.

```
finalList = []
for d in dList:
    innerList = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        innerList.append(setupTime(k, v))
    finalList.append(innerList)
```

But this can be reduced to nested list comprehensions:

```
finalList = [[setupTime(k, v) for (k,v) in d.items()] 
             for d in dList]
```